# jquery tipsy two tips in the same time

Tags: jquery, tipsy

I am using [jQuery Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) in my project. In the social media tags I want to show on the top, social media name and on the bottom, page sharing counts like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**

My links like this:

```
<a class="twitter tip-n tip-s" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=text&url=page" title="Twitter" rel="17 tweets"></a>
```

And jQuery code part like this:

```
$('.tip-n').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 's', html: true});
$('.tip-s').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 'n', html: true, title: 'rel'});
```

Of course it did not work. I googled but I did not find anything. Could you help me?

Comment: Similar to Girish's answer below - http://jsfiddle.net/4wcsatLn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Garath asked `plugin` does not support two tool tip on same element, but you can do it another way.. `warp` `<a>` element by `<span>` and apply another tool tip on `<span>` element

```
    <span rel="17 tweets" class="tip-s">
      <a class="twitter tip-n" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=text&url=page" title="Twitter">ICON</a>
    </span>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.tip-n').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 's', html: true});
        $('.tip-s').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 'n', html: true, title: 'rel'})
    });

   </script>
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('.tip-n').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 's', html: true});
  $('.tip-s').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 'n', html: true, title: 'rel'})
})
```

```html
<link href="http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/stylesheets/tipsy.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<span rel="17 tweets" class="tip-s">
<a class="twitter tip-n" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=text&url=page" title="Twitter">ICON</a>
</span>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h6tth676/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much. This must be the difference between looking and seeing. Really cool solution.

Answer (score 2):

I check the [tipsy source code](https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy/blob/master/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js) and it is impossible without changes in original code :)

The change could be done in `show` and `enter` function. In my opinion you should create method `showN` witch will show text above your element (hardcode in it north position), and analogical `showS`. In `enter` method just call both and you will be done.